# Does Hiberate ignore changed state of object if you ultimately delete it?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a problem in some code where Hiberate seems to ignore changed made to an entity right before it is deleted. This application has 2 tables for such objects - one that keeps the current state and one that keeps copies of the rows in the first to keep a history of the object. A stored procedure copies the row from the first to the second when changes are made.

There is a service method for editing and it is marked @Transactional with no arguments (so REQUIRED is the default). The service method calls several DAO methods. Each method is also marked @Transactional and gets the Session object from the SessionFactory's getCurrentSession() method.

When we want to delete the object we first want to update it to record the user id of the person who deleted it so the history table will have a record with this information. Then we use session.delete() to delete it. The problem is that Hibernate ignores this update of the record before the deletion perhaps due to some optimizing logic that decides why update a row that is going to be deleted.

We tried putting the update in a separate method and marking it REQUIRES_NEW. But that seems to cause irregular deadlock issues in the DB2 backing database.

Hibernate makes it hard to determine when the commit happens as well when you just rely on the annotations. Does anyone have an idea on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

you should try flushing changes done to the object by doing `session.flush()` and then `delete()` it

Hopefully hibernate wont ignore the changes with `flush` performed already.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this might be executing a native SQL query for the update, then perform the deletion.

Comment: Hope this is what you were looking for.